# i hope the game view is in the player and followed the mouse but exported the view is fixed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a character

however, exported the view is fixed for some reason and I did not set any camera.

Just want to know if any of you can solve this problem!
i try in tag to set the main camera and i use the camera 1 to move the perspective. when i test the game in unity all function is work , but exported the view is fixed strange location, not the character.

```
public class MoveManager : MonoBehaviour`
{
  
//public Transform model;
public float rotatespeed =32f;
public float rotatelerp = 8 ;
#region 

private float X;
private float Y;
public float Xmax ; 
public float Xmin ; 

//private const float min_angle_y = -89f;
//private const float max_angle_y = 89f;

void Update ()
{

X += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
Y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
Y += Mathf.Clamp(Y,Xmin ,Xmax);

this.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(X, Y,0);
```

Comment: In the game window of your editor, which aspect ratio do you use? If you are seeing issues after building the application, it is most likely because the build resolution does not match the test resolution.